# sql query with mysqli and php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm doing two simple insert in my db with mysqli. This is the code:

```
  $aux=json_decode($_POST['arr']);

  $cont = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $_POST["k"]);
  $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $aux[0]);
  $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $aux[1]);
  $place = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $aux[2]);
  $topic = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $aux[3]);
  $lat = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $aux[4]);
  $lng = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $aux[5]);

$card_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $_POST["aux2"]);

$id2=$_COOKIE['id'];

echo mysqli_error($connessione);

     $result=mysqli_query($connessione,"select meeting_id from meeting order 
 by meeting_id desc limit 1;");
 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 $wPrima=$row[0];
  $wDopo=$wPrima+1;
     $sql1="start transaction; insert into meeting 
  (card_id,user_id,title,place,date,topic,lat,lng) values 
 ('$card_id','$id2','$title','$place','$date','$topic','$lat','$lng');";

    for($i=6;$i<$cont;$i++) 
 {  $part_id+$i = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $aux[i]);  
 $number = rand(0,1);
 $sql1 .="insert into invite values ('".$part_id+$i."','$wDopo','$number'); 
 commit work;";
 }


mysqli_multi_query($connessione,$sql1);

echo mysqli_error($connessione);
   $json_data = array(

                                "result" => 1
                         );
$json = json_encode($json_data);
echo $json;
```

I'm passing an array with ajax and using the values of the array for the insert. With the first query I take the last id insert in the table meeting (+1). After I create the "sql1" query to do with mysqli_multi_query. Is this wrong? It doesn't add any values in the tables and the console doesn't give me any error.

Comment: Before i tried only to add a row in meeting and it worked. After i added the transaction and doesn't work.

Comment: I think the error could be in the line 
$part_id+$i
I need to have something like part_id1 , part_id2 ecc.